# Custom post type request switches to media request

Tags: plugins, posts

I am using Modern Tribe's Events Calendar Plugin http://tri.be/shop/wordpress-events-calendar/

I use this on multiple sites, but I have a really weird problem. I've already checked to ensure it is not a plugin conflict, and followed all the troubleshooting steps from Tribe.

What's happening is that Wordpress is switching my custom post type request to a media file request.

I get a 404 page from this URL: http://elakenews.com/local-event/great-pumpkin-hunt/

The post request is switching to a media attachment request (see debugger results: http://d.pr/i/6kg9 )

Any ideas? I am stumped..

Comment: Do you have a media file with exactly the same slug by any chance?

Comment: @adrian7 No - it's the same error with all custom post types on the event calendar. I have already reset permalinks and change the slugs for the event calendar too. See here is another one:http://d.pr/i/11FPw